# lemmon style proof for logic

Tags: logic

Does exist a package for Lemmon style proof in Logic? something like:
http://logik.phl.univie.ac.at/~chris/gateway/formular-uk-bau.html

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a package which is not on CTAN but can be found at: http://phloxgroup.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/lemmon-style-natural-deduction-proofs-in-latex/ (for some reason¹, the author saved the file as a .doc file, just *save as* .sty file and it will work).

I haven't thoroughly tested the package, but you can do things like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nd3}
\begin{document}
    \begin{ND}[Anothter Proof][ ][\awidth{the proof}][\rwidth{the proof}][.8\linewidth]
        \ndl{} {$a=a$} {$= $I}\label{1}
        \ndl{} {$\forall x\,x =x$ }{\ref{1},$\forall$I}\label{2}
    \end{ND}
\end{document}
```

(example taken from the [manual](http://phloxgroup.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/nd-manual2.pdf))[image]

You may also want to take a look at the packages listed at: http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/ maybe you'll find something interesting

--

¹Actually, the reason is explained in the blog

Comment: Could I ask you how did you install the custom package on your pc? I'm trying to follow other answered question on this topic but I failed so far,thanks again

Comment: @alessandro I just put the .sty file in the same directory of the .tex file. If you want to install it system wide, you should copy the .sty file in `~/texmf/tex/latex/local/nd/` and then issue a `texhash` command. However the installation process depends on your OS (this works for Linux), see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1167/24483 for a more accurate explanation.