# Natural deduction like proof

Tags: theorems

I'm not sure what the right word is for this kind of proof (in the picture):

[image]

It is some kind of combination of natural deduction and normal math proofs. I'm wondering how I could do this in LaTeX. I doesn't really need to look exactly like this. In the picture, I've put statement 6-11 to the right for example, but this is not really necessary. More generally I would like something as:

**Given**
1. statement
2. statement
**Ⅰ**    Statement to prove
3. hypothese
   4. statement (justification)
5. statement (justification)
**II**    Other statement to prove
etc. etc.

Any suggestion for doing something like this in LaTeX, maybe some packages that I could use ?

Comment: take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147063/lemmon-style-proof-for-logic/147065#147065

Comment: possibly related: [Which packages/practices are relevant for writing Structured Derivations? (similar to Dijkstra's calculational style of proofs)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49416)

Comment: @cmhughes Interesting !

Comment: You might find http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/ helpful (scroll down to Fitch-style layouts which are formatted in the way I think you have in mind for natural deduction). There might be something helpful there even though you are not doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: unfortunately, the visual isn't really intelligible to me.  but you may be looking for something like what is described in this tugboat article: [ProofCheck: Writing and checking complete proofs in LaTeX](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-2/tb95neveln.pdf) by Bob Neveln and Bob Alps.

Comment: @barbarabeeton http://snag.gy/Iv7sU.jpg Here I did a proof in english, with this kind of style.

Comment: @Kasper -- thank you for the link to the example.  this does look more like the finch-style proof layout than what was described in the tugboat article.

Comment: @Kasper - the example you posted for barbarabeeton is more fitch-like than the first. If that format is good, I definitely think you should look at the packages for formatting fitch-style natural deduction proofs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having a lot of problems accessing the site right now but perhaps this will be useful. It does not look quite like [the image you posted](http://snag.gy/Iv7sU.jpg) but it does maintain the basic structure. It supplements `lplfitch` with two new commands, `\given` and `\toprove{}`, to help keep the formatting of your variation consistent. Note that the commands beginning `\l...` are from the package. You need not use them if you prefer to type the full mathematical symbols directly or if their names are counter-intuitive from a mathematical perspective. Anyway, I hope it may be useful in some way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lplfitch}
\renewcommand{\formula}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}
\newcommand*{\fitchline}{\cline{1-1}\\[-2ex]}
\newcounter{thingstoprove}
\newcommand*{\given}{%
  \setcounter{thingstoprove}{0}%
   & {\bfseries Given}\\\fitchline}
\newcommand*{\toprove}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{thingstoprove}%
  \\[-2ex] & {\bfseries \Roman{thingstoprove}}\formula{\; #1} & To show\\\fitchline}
\setlength{\fitchprfwidth}{.7\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\noindent\fitchprf{%
  \given
  \pline[1.]{\lall a,b \in \mathcal{Z}\ ( a|b \liff \lis c \in \mathcal{Z}\ ac = b )}[Pr.]\\
  \pline[2.]{\lall a,b \in \mathcal{Z}, p \in \mathcal{P}\ ( p|ab \lif p|a \lor p|b )}[Pr.]\\
  \pline[3.]{\lall x \in \mathcal{Q}\ ( \lis m,n \in \mathcal{Z},  n \neq 0 : x = \frac{m}{n}, gcd(m,n) = 1 )}[Pr.]}{%
  \toprove{\sqrt{2} \notin \mathcal{Q}}
  \subproof{\pline[4.]{\sqrt{2} \in \mathcal{Q}}[Ass.\ for \emph{reductio}]}{%
    \pline[5.]{\sqrt{2} = \frac{m}{n} \text{ for some } m, n \in \mathcal{Z}, gcd (m,n) = 1}[3,4]\\
    \pline[6.]{2n^2 = m^2}[multiply by 2; square]\\
    \pline[7.]{2|m^2}[1,6]\\
    \pline[8.]{2|m}[2,7]\\
    \pline[9.]{m = 2c \text{ for some } c \in \mathcal{Z}}[1,8]\\
    \pline[10.]{2n^2 = 4c^2}[6,9]\\
    \pline[11.]{n^2 = 2c^2}[divide by 2]\\
    \pline[12.]{2|n^2}[1,11]\\
    \pline[13.]{2|n}[2,12]\\
    \pline[14.]{gcd(m,n) \geq 2}[8,13]\\
    \pline[15.]{\lfalse}[\lfalsei{5}{14}]
    }
  \pline[16.]{\sqrt{2} \notin \mathcal{Q}}[\lnoti{4--15}]
}\bigskip

\noindent\fitchprf{%
  \given
  \pline[1.]{statement}\\
  \pline[2.]{statement}}
  {%
    \toprove{\text{Statement to prove}}
    \subproof{\pline[3.]{hypothesis}[Hyp.]}{%
      \pline[4.]{statement}[justification]
      }
    \pline[5.]{statement}[justification]\\
    \toprove{\text{Other statement to prove}}
    \ellipsesline
}

\end{document}
```

[image: fitch-style proofs with lplfitch]

If you like to live dangerously, the following should give precisely the same output with automatic management of line numbering for proof lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lplfitch}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\formula}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}
\newcommand*{\fitchline}{\cline{1-1}\\[-2ex]}
\newcounter{thingstoprove}
\newcommand*{\given}{%
  \setcounter{thingstoprove}{0}%
   & {\bfseries Given}\\\fitchline}
\newcommand*{\toprove}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{thingstoprove}%
  \\[-2ex] & {\bfseries \Roman{thingstoprove}}\formula{\; #1} & To show\\\fitchline}
\setlength{\fitchprfwidth}{.7\textwidth}
\newcounter{plineno}
\newcommand*{\reallyresetplineno}{\setcounter{plineno}{0}}
\let\resetplineno\reallyresetplineno
\pretocmd{\fitchprf}{\resetplineno}{\GenericWarning{Hackery}{Successfully prepended code to fitchprf.}}{\GenericWarning{Hackery}{Failed to patch fitchprf. Sorry, you will need to manage line numbering yourself.}}
\apptocmd{\fitchprf}{\global\let\resetplineno\reallyresetplineno}{\GenericWarning{Hackery}{Successfully appended code to fitchprf.}}{\GenericWarning{Hackery}{Failed to patch fitchprf. Sorry, you will need to manage line numbering yourself.}}
\pretocmd{\subproof}{\global\let\resetplineno\relax}{\GenericWarning{Hackery}{Successfully prepended code to subproof.}}{\GenericWarning{Hackery}{Failed to patch subproof. Sorry, you will need to manage line numbering yourself.}}
\makeatletter
  \patchcmd{\pline}{\@empty}{\stepcounter{plineno}\arabic{plineno}.}{\GenericWarning{Hackery}{Successfully patched pline.}}{\GenericWarning{Hackery}{Failed to patch pline. Sorry, you will need to manage line numbering yourself.}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent\fitchprf{%
  \given
  \pline{\lall a,b \in \mathcal{Z}\ ( a|b \liff \lis c \in \mathcal{Z}\ ac = b )}[Pr.]\\
  \pline{\lall a,b \in \mathcal{Z}, p \in \mathcal{P}\ ( p|ab \lif p|a \lor p|b )}[Pr.]\\
  \pline{\lall x \in \mathcal{Q}\ ( \lis m,n \in \mathcal{Z},  n \neq 0 : x = \frac{m}{n}, gcd(m,n) = 1 )}[Pr.]}{%
  \toprove{\sqrt{2} \notin \mathcal{Q}}
  \subproof{\pline{\sqrt{2} \in \mathcal{Q}}[Ass.\ for \emph{reductio}]}{%
    \pline{\sqrt{2} = \frac{m}{n} \text{ for some } m, n \in \mathcal{Z}, gcd (m,n) = 1}[3,4]\\
    \pline{2n^2 = m^2}[multiply by 2; square]\\
    \pline{2|m^2}[1,6]\\
    \pline{2|m}[2,7]\\
    \pline{m = 2c \text{ for some } c \in \mathcal{Z}}[1,8]\\
    \pline{2n^2 = 4c^2}[6,9]\\
    \pline{n^2 = 2c^2}[divide by 2]\\
    \pline{2|n^2}[1,11]\\
    \pline{2|n}[2,12]\\
    \pline{gcd(m,n) \geq 2}[8,13]\\
    \pline{\lfalse}[\lfalsei{5}{14}]
    }
  \pline{\sqrt{2} \notin \mathcal{Q}}[\lnoti{4--15}]
}\bigskip

\noindent\fitchprf{%
  \given
  \pline{statement}\\
  \pline{statement}}
  {%
    \toprove{\text{Statement to prove}}
    \subproof{\pline{hypothesis}[Hyp.]}{%
      \pline{statement}[justification]
      }
    \pline{statement}[justification]\\
    \toprove{\text{Other statement to prove}}
    \ellipsesline
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to define a counter for `\pline`? Is seems that typing line numbers manually is not a very efficient (nor robust) thing to do.

Comment: @KevinC See the addition to my answer. This gives just the same output but manages number of proof lines automagically. Since this patches the commands of `lplfitch` rather more seriously than the original code (it uses the facilities of etoolbox), this is likely to be more fragile. But it does seem to work with the examples I used, at least.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much !! This is awesome :)

Comment: @Kasper No problem. It was interesting - I've never used this package or the etoolbox patching commands before. But I've wanted an excuse to play with the latter!